# Populate data in dynamically loaded GridView using WCF

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf, gridview

A `GridView` is loaded dynamically onto a form in asp.net 4.5

```
GridView dGrid = new GridView(); 
dGrid.ID = string.Format("grd{0}",this.mGroup.Index);
dGrid.EnableViewState = false; 
dGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dGrid.ShowHeader = true;
dGrid.CssClass = StyleClass.Grid;
dGrid.ShowFooter = false;
dGrid.BorderWidth = 0;
dGrid.GridLines = GridLines.None;
Controls.AddAt(0,dGrid);
```

After this I would like to re-populate the control depending on a search criteria, and for this an ajax call to a WCF service is made.

```
function ajaxCall(actTitle, url, token) {
var elemTitles = new Array();
$(".formMargin").each(function () {
    elemTitles.push($(this).text());
});
var arForm = $("#Form1").serializeArray();
$.ajax({
    url: url + "/Ajax.svc/CallAction",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ formVars: arForm, elementTitles: elemTitles, actTitle: actTitle, token: token }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
        //Re-populate GridView here
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert("An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

As you can see just a normal Ajax request to WCF. I have seen some other topics where data is appended to the grid using `table` low level operations with strings manipulation, I'm wondering if there's not a less error-prone way to re-populate a GridView on client side.

Comment: On the client, there is no real `GridView`; it is all `HTML`.  So, you will have to deal with `tr` and `td`.  Otherwise, use a `WebMethod` in `ASPX` page, call that inside your success, pass data, bind that data to GridView inside WebMethod

Comment: There's no reference to the GridView on the server as it's loaded dynamically

Comment: never mind, even using WebMethod is not possible as you can't access other page members using WebMethod

Comment: Is there a reason to add the data to the GridView? You could just render a table client side.

Comment: In your server side, you can create a ajaxmethod or webapi that calls your wcf service. With returned data, set the DataSource property of GridView and use the RenderControl method to get the rendered html. So you can return this html to your javascript function and replace the content.